# /system/csc/customer.xml can't open file?

Tags: android

I've been messing around with libGDX, and prior to installing a custom rom onto my Tab S 8.4, I've been able to deploy applications to it from intellij.

Since installing this custom rom, I get the following message when deploying my application:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-sm_t700-320424254c91115d
Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\NewFolder\android\build\outputs\apk\android-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.mygdx.game.android
Installing com.mygdx.game.android
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.mygdx.game.android"
/system/csc/customer.xml can't open file
Aborted


Launching application: com.mygdx.game.android/com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.mygdx.game.android/com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
/system/csc/customer.xml can't open file
Aborted
```

Launching the same application within an emulator works as expected. I've read about possible issues concerning launchers and verifying apps through USB, but I have toggled either of them every which way and can't seem to change this result.

I've tried to flash the rom several times at this point, and have downloaded it on separate occasions, so a botched flash doesn't seem likely. I'm hoping to not have to revert to stock.

Thanks for any guidance in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting the device back to its stock rom, and applications are deploying like they used to. Not the ideal solution, but it's better than not being able to debug applications on the device.